# A notation in Theorem 3.4 in Chapter 1 of Hartshorne’s Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to read the proof of Theorem 3.4 in chapter 1 in Hartshorne’s Algebraic Geometry. In the proof there is a notation that seems quite confusing to me:

Here is the related context (Sorry for using a screenshot rather than posting with latex in my own language)
[image]

I am confused with the notation $I(Y)S_{(x_i)}$. Here $S$ is the polynomial ring $k[x_0, \cdots, x_n]$, $S_{(x_i)}$ is the subring with degree 0 in the localized ring $S_{x_i}$. $I(Y)$ is the homogeneous ideal of $Y$. But what is the meaning of $I(Y)S_{(x_i)}$? The isomorphism should send element in $I(Y_i)$ to degree 0 in $S_{x_i}$, but simply multiplying $I(Y)$ and $S_{(x_i)}$ seems not satisfying this. For example, taking $Y$ to be the points satisfying $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$, then $f(x, y) = x^2+y^2-1$ is sent to $(x/z)^2 + (y/z)^2 -1 $. I cannot realize it as a pattern like $I(Y)S_{(z)}$. If writing it as $(x^2+y^2-z^2) \cdot 1/z^2$, then $1/z^2$ is not has degree 0. But writing it as $1 \cdot ((x/z)^2 + (y/z)^2 -1)$, then $1$ is not in $I(Y)$.

I read this [Hartshorne notation in Theorem 3.4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798552/hartshorne-notation-in-theorem-3-4) but still cannot figure it out.

Staring at it for a few minutes, I am thinking is it a typo here? Should it be $I(Y)S_{x_i}$ rather than $I(Y)S_{(x_i)}$?

Thanks!

Here is exercise 2.6 in chapter 1 for cross references. Here $\varphi_i$ sends $[x_0, \cdots, x_n]$ to $(x_0/x_i, \cdots, x_n/x_i)$ omitting $x_i/x_i$.

[image]

Comment: What‘s in Ex. 2.6?

Comment: @Wuestenfux I attached ex2.6 too. I haven’t do this exercise yet and cannot see why the author cross referencing it.  My major confusion is the meaning the notation $I(Y)S_{(x_i)}$.

Comment: I got it from the answer in the linked question now. It's $I(Y)S_{x_i} \cap S_{(x_i)}$

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question

Comment: @mbert Thank you. I would update an answer soon in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment and from the linked question, the notation $I(Y)S_{(x_i)}$ should be $I(Y)S_{x_i} \cap S_{(x_i)}$, i.e., same as $I(Y)_{(x_i)}$.

It has been some time since I posted the question, and temporally I skipped the classical content, moved to maybe a more understandable book like Vakil's FOAG, and forgot perhaps some context for the theorem here.

Nevertheless, I have to say that the notations related to degree $0$ summand of localization of graded ring seem confusing almost everywhere. (Vakil uses the notation $(S_{x_i})_0$, and the Stacks project uses the same notation as Hartshorne's.)